# PHP NumberFormatter print ISO 3 currency code

Tags: php, currency

Is there any way to retrieve a notation of the currency like the following with the PHP NumberFormatter class:

```
100,00 EUR
```

Basically instead of the symbol € I want the ISO 3 code.

The alternative would be to omit the symbol completely, but I still want to keep the type as NumberFormatter:CURRENCY. Don't know how to do this either.

Is it about str_replace in the end?

Comment: Do you have a data-source of the ISO currency codes? IIRC PHP does not have one built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set manually the currency symbol, with

`$nf->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '<my symbol>');`

& then use the `format()` method for formatting. But i think, that's not what you want. For example:

```
$nf_en = new \NumberFormatter('en', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$nf_en->setTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, 'EUR');
$nf_en->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, 'EUR');

$nf_de = new \NumberFormatter('de', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$nf_de->setTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, 'EUR');
$nf_de->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, 'EUR');

echo $nf_en->format(1); // this will print 'EUR1.00'!
echo $nf_de->format(1); // this will print 'EUR 1,00'!
```

If you set the currency code to `''`, still there will be locales, where the formatted strings will start (or end) with white space(s). It would be easier to use the `NumberFormatter` to format as a decimal number.